# How to cut the line made by border in css?

Tags: html, css

I created an "progress bar" for my website. I want to cut the line so it starts and ends in those dots. Tried different margins and stuff but that is not the way. Also I have a problem with text below dots. Can I force wrapping them into more narrow texts so that they keep more distance from each other?
[Current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZlUw.png)
[Desired design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyJ6l.png)

Here is the code:

```css
.wraper {
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.container_wraper {
  border-top: 2px solid #293ff9;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.link {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.link a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #293ff9;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/* .link:first-child {
    margin-left: -55px;
  }
  
  .link:last-child {
    margin-right: -55px;
  } */

.link::after {
  content: "";
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  top: -18px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.link:hover::after {
  background: #293ff9;
}

.lead {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 1px 0 1px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  font: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wraper">

  <ul class="container_wraper">
    <li class="link"><a href="">Materiały</a></li>
    <li class="link"><a href="">Algorytmy</a></li>
    <li class="link active"><a href="">Szkolenia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="lead">
    <p class="lead1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit eligendi non id doloremque aliquid provident nobis consectetur recus.!</p>
    <p class="lead2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius vel perferendis repellat laborum iure laudantium ex ipsa repellendus dignissimos iusto.</p>
    <p class="lead3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae officiis quae mollitia totam quis cumque a iste sapiente impedit neque illo eos .</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may use linear gradients

Comment: Could you please add line height for paragraph. I'm confused that is design .lead {line-height: normal;}

Answer (score 1):

1. To trim the beginnings and ends of lines, you can use this CSS code.
   I removed the `border-bottom` and used the `::before` selector to
   add the blue line. Additionally, I used the `transform` property to
   linearly adjust the line created by the `::before` selector. I also
   eliminated the fixed top property value of 18 and replaced it with
   the transform property, ensuring the dot aligns well with various
   sizes.
2. To achieve a narrower text, you can use ‍`letter-spacing`, or in my
   opinion, you can use the font that is present in the desired design.

```css
.wraper {
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.container_wraper {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.link {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.link::before {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #293ff9;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

.link:last-child:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
}

.link a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #293ff9;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
}

/* .link:first-child {
    margin-left: -55px;
  }
  
  .link:last-child {
    margin-right: -55px;
  } */

.link::after {
  content: "";
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.link:hover::after {
  background: #293ff9;
}

.lead {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 1px 0 1px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  font: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wraper">

  <ul class="container_wraper">
    <li class="link"><a href="">Materiały</a></li>
    <li class="link"><a href="">Algorytmy</a></li>
    <li class="link active"><a href="">Szkolenia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="lead">
    <p class="lead1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit eligendi non id doloremque aliquid provident nobis consectetur recus.!</p>
    <p class="lead2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius vel perferendis repellat laborum iure laudantium ex ipsa repellendus dignissimos iusto.</p>
    <p class="lead3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae officiis quae mollitia totam quis cumque a iste sapiente impedit neque illo eos .</p>
  </div>
</div>
```